# showing multiple data which meets certain conditions-issue in PANDAS

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

I am working in PANDAS with Python and I am looking at a weather CSV file. I am able to pull data from it with no problem. However, I am not able to pull data that meets certain criteria such as when to show which days have the temperature above 100 degrees.

I have this as my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.read_csv('csv/weather.csv')

print(df[[df.MaxTemperatureF > 100 ]])
```

That last line is where I think I have my problem. The error traceback that I now get, after doing the steps below, is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "weather.py", line 40, in <module>
print(df[df['MaxTemperatureF' > 100]])
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
Mikes-MBP-2:dataframes mikecuddy$ python3 weather.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "weather.py", line 41, in <module>
print(df[[df.MaxTemperatureF > 100 ]])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-     
packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1991, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_array(key)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-  
packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2028, in _getitem_array
(len(key), len(self.index)))
 ValueError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 360.
```

I have been doing a tutorial at: http://www.gregreda.com/2013/10/26/working-with-pandas-dataframes/ Again any help would be great! Thank you!

df.info() information:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 360 entries, 0 to 359
Data columns (total 23 columns):
PST                           360 non-null object
MaxTemperatureF               359 non-null float64
Mean TemperatureF             359 non-null float64
Min TemperatureF              359 non-null float64
Max Dew PointF                359 non-null float64
MeanDew PointF                359 non-null float64
Min DewpointF                 359 non-null float64
Max Humidity                  359 non-null float64
Mean Humidity                359 non-null float64
Min Humidity                 359 non-null float64
Max Sea Level PressureIn     359 non-null float64
Mean Sea Level PressureIn    359 non-null float64
Min Sea Level PressureIn     359 non-null float64
Max VisibilityMiles          355 non-null float64
Mean VisibilityMiles         355 non-null float64
Min VisibilityMiles          355 non-null float64
Max Wind SpeedMPH            359 non-null float64
Mean Wind SpeedMPH           359 non-null float64
Max Gust SpeedMPH            211 non-null float64
PrecipitationIn               360 non-null float64
CloudCover                   343 non-null float64
Events                       18 non-null object
WindDirDegrees               360 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(20), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 64.8+ KB
None
```

Comment: For the first question,

    print(df[df['MaxTemperatureF'] > 100 ])

Should be what you're looking for. I dont understand your other questions though, cant you call head() after filtering?

Comment: Maybe max temperature is stored as a string?

Comment: yeah, the error message that I get is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(df[df['MaxTemperatureF' > 100]])
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int() However not sure where exactly to place the int()

Comment: Have you tried importing the data without `header=None`?

Comment: okay taking out header=None gets the data how I want! That problem solved now for the print(df[df['MaxTemperatureF'] > 100 ])

Comment: In your MaxTemperatureF column are the values only numbers or do some possibly look something like 95F? That would throw off your attempts to convert to float

Comment: nope-did a search and nothing like that came up

Comment: Re: `ValueError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 360.`. Remove double brackets: `df[df.MaxTemperatureF > 100]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the max temperature you can specify a converter function:

```
df = pd.read_csv('csv/weather.csv', converters={'MaxTemperatureF':float})
```

Edit: as @ptrj mentions in a comment you can do this to substitute `np.nan` for string values in the `MaxTemperatureF` column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('csv/weather.csv', 
                 converters={'MaxTemperatureF':
                             lambda x: try: return float(x); 
                                       except ValueError: return np.nan;})
```

Edit2: @ptrj's solution since he can't write it up in a comment...

```
def my_conv(x): 
    try: 
        return float(x)
    except ValueError: 
        return np.nan

df = pd.read_csv('csv/weather.csv', converters={'MaxTemperatureF': my_conv})
```

Other things:

- If the first row of the csv file has the headers then don't pass `header=0`.
- Being that you already have the header now you don't need to specify `cols=...`
- The default `sep` is ',' so you don't need to specify that.

Comment: when I do df = pd.read_csv('csv/weather.csv', converters={'MaxTemperatureF':float}) I get this error message: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: There must be strings in there. Can you clean up the source file?

Comment: Yes, how do I clean up the source file to purge it of those strings? Remember I am knew to PANDAS!

Comment: Maybe this will help: `converters={'MaxTemperatureF': my_conv}`, where `def my_conv(x): try: return float(x); except: return np.nan`.

Comment: I updated my issue and now have a new error. Please see above

Comment: Thanks, @ptrj. Updated answer.

Comment: Using converters={'MaxTemperatureF': my_conv}, where def my_conv(x): try: return float(x); except: return np.nan only gets me this error:                             File "weather.py", line 14
    lambda x: try: return float(x); 
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @MikeCuddy Write the definition of `my_conv` properly indented (and without semicolons). I can't do it in a comment.

Comment: @ptrj: added your solution to my answer. Thank you for it, btw.

Comment: Yeah I put in the my_conv correctly, however, I did fix the problem. In print(df[[df.MaxTemperatureF > 100 ]]) I had one set of extra brackets. It was supposed to be print(df[df.MaxTemperatureF > 100 ])

Answer (score 1):

Try this: You have '()" instead of [].

```
print(df[df.MaxTemperatureF.astype(float) > 100 ])
```

notes:

```
df.isnull().sum() 
df.dropna()
df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Still getting the ValueError: could not convert string to float: Error message

Comment: Run:   df.isnull().sum()  Checking for null, or nan.. which could be stings, then  then try  dropna() which removes -- But you may to fillna(0) to keep the data but replace nan with "0"