# ignoring rows with unmatching dtype in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm specifying dtypes while reading a huge CSV in `pandas`:

```
pd.read_csv('29_2016/data.csv', 
            error_bad_lines=False, 
            encoding='utf-8', 
            dtype={'a': str, 'b': np.float64, 'c':np.float64}, 
            na_values=['na'], quotechar='"')
```

but there are some "bad" rows in my data and they don't match the dtype due to some data preparation problems. For example, I might have strings in column b or column c.

Is there any way to ignore these bad rows while reading the CSV using `pandas` `read_csv`?

Error:

```
pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:7988)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:8244)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:9261)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas/parser.c:10654)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas/parser.c:11891)()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: some string "\
```

Comment: What about reading the whole file and select the desired rows by using a approach like this (needs to be adopted for rows instead of columns for sure): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271581/selecting-pandas-columns-by-dtype

Comment: What happens, given the provided code where you define the dtypes, when pandas encounters a *bad row* (that it can't cast to the specified dtype)?

Comment: I think you can use `converters` argument as in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38378291/5717589) (with try-except), then drop nan's if needed.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this? I'd be really interested to know if you found a solution.

Comment: Is there a better way to handle this issue. proposed solution was of 2017, maybe something has changed.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the discussion in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2570, it would seem that the intended way of dealing malformed numeric values is to load the data without forcing the `dtypes` and then calling `pd.to_numeric()` (or the other functions of the `pd.to_XXXXX()` family as needed) on the columns. (In fact, in the discussion mentioned above suggested `convert_objects()` which has since been deprecated).

So, in the case at issue here, I would do the following:

```
data = pd.read_csv('29_2016/data.csv', 
            error_bad_lines=False, 
            encoding='utf-8', 
            na_values=['na'], quotechar='"')
```

and then

```
data.b = pd.to_numeric(data.b,errors='coerce')  # 'coerce' results in NaN for entries that can't be converted
data.c = pd.to_numeric(data.c,errors='coerce')

data = data[data.b.notnull() & data.c.notnull()]  # filter out rows with NaN
```

Comment: I don't think that quite works if you want integers. (You have to cast to int at the end.) It's irritating that this isn't simply part of `read_csv`.

Comment: Would be nice if `to_numeric` had a `"skip"` option too