# How can I read CSV file from function attribute into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I wrote a function that calculates the log returns of a dataframe. The arguments of the function takes the csv file name and should return a dataframe of the log returns of the csv file. The csv file is already located on my machine. Below is the code I am trying to execute.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def portfolio_log_returns(portfolio):
    dataset = pd.read_csv(portfolio)
    log_returns = pd.DataFrame(columns=dataset.columns)

    for col in dataset.columns:
        log_returns[col] = np.log(dataset[col]/dataset[col].shift(1))
    
    log_returns = log_returns.dropna()
    return log_returns

log_returns_df = portfolio_log_returns('some_csv_file.csv')
```

I get the following error when I try to execute the code:

```
log_returns_df = portfolio_log_returns('some_csv_file.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:171 in _na_arithmetic_op
result = func(left, right)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py:239 in evaluate
return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)  # type: ignore[misc]

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py:128 in _evaluate_numexpr
result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py:70 in _evaluate_standard
return op(a, b)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'NoneType'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[4], line 1
log_returns_df = portfolio_log_returns('some_csv_file.csv')

  Cell In[1], line 9 in portfolio_log_returns
log_returns[col] = np.log(dataset[col]/dataset[col].shift(1))

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py:81 in new_method
return method(self, other)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py:210 in __truediv__
return self._arith_method(other, operator.truediv)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:6112 in _arith_method
return base.IndexOpsMixin._arith_method(self, other, op)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py:1348 in _arith_method
result = ops.arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:232 in arithmetic_op
res_values = _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op)  # type: ignore[arg-type]

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:178 in _na_arithmetic_op
result = _masked_arith_op(left, right, op)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:116 in _masked_arith_op
result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check the `dtypes` of your dataframe. Some of the cols are strings and not numbers

Comment: As what the above comment said, it is having problems with the division operation concerning the value types involved. The str should be changed to int or float first.

Comment: pls put the sample  data from the content of the csv file in ur question to see the data.

Comment: Where can I upload the file? The file is to large to put in the question

Comment: read the data `dataset = pd.read_csv(portfolio)` and just print out `dataset.dtypes` and report it by editing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate your issue with a csv with the following data:

```
value1,value2,value3
1,2.2,3.3
4,5.5,"6.6"
8,"9.9a",10.1
28,"9.97",10.16
38,"19.9",106.1
```

As Pandas can't convert that `"9.9a"` to a number, so it makes the whole field a type `object` instead of `int64` or `float64`. You can find out which field by adding `print(col, dataset[col].dtype)` to your loop.

[As suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46788684/19038086) if you want to just skip those, you can add a `pd.to_numeric` on the column in question, or all of them since you are executing the command on all of them. A viable solution may look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def portfolio_log_returns(portfolio):
    dataset = pd.read_csv(portfolio)
    log_returns = pd.DataFrame(columns=dataset.columns)

    for col in dataset.columns:
        # print(col, dataset[col].dtype)
        dataset[col] = pd.to_numeric(dataset[col], errors='coerce')
        log_returns[col] = np.log(dataset[col]/dataset[col].shift(1))
    
    log_returns = log_returns.dropna()
    return log_returns

log_returns_df = portfolio_log_returns('some_csv_file.csv')
```