# Can pandas read_csv use dtype and write NaN on unparsable data?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas to read a csv that has some poorly-formatted lines -- fields that should be numeric, but are actually strings. I'd like my dataframe to have numeric dtypes, and have NaNs where the field isn't parsable.

My current solution is read everything as strings, then recast the numeric columns. This is cumbersome to large CSVs

```
df = pd.read_csv(mycsv)
for numcol in numeric_columns:
    df[numcol] = pd.to_numeric(df[numcol], errors='coerce')
```

Is there a way to do this operation in one shot at read-time?

Comment: You may try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38378291/5717589

Comment: Will give it a try - looks like it might be inefficient for large CSV imports?

Comment: @ptrj looks like this method will at best allow me to load my numeric data as `float64`. Really would like to be able to use smaller int datatypes.

Comment: Yes, I didn't measure it but it's likely it's inefficient. You could do `int(x)` instead of `float(x)` and some other exceptional value instead of NaN.

Comment: Oh right.. I forgot that integer types don't have a `NaN` representation. I think this solution will suffice - thanks!